# Rails 3 array output

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

This is probably a really easy problem to solve, but I have a query that pulls data from two models. The only thing I want to see from this query would be the averages (numbers at the end of each string), in an array. However, the output currently looks like this:

```
{"[\"Orthodontist\", 2011, 4]":"545625.5","[\"Orthodontist\", 2011, 3]":"534927.0","[\"Orthodontist\", 2011, 2]":"524438.5","[\"Orthodontist\", 2011, 1]":"514155.5"}
```

I want the array to look like this:

```
[545625.5, 534927.0, 524438.5, 514155.5]
```

The code looks like this:

```
<%= Quarter.includes(:client).group('clients.specialty', 'quarters.year','quarters.quarter').limit(4)
.order('quarters.created_at DESC').average('quarters.collections').to_json %>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `to_json` add `values`

```
<%= Quarter.includes(:client).group('clients.specialty', 'quarters.year','quarters.quarter').limit(4)
.order('quarters.created_at DESC').average('quarters.collections').values.to_json %>
```

Comment: Oh man, thanks! That's just what I needed. I haven't used ".values" before. So now the output is: ["545625.5","534927.0","524438.5","514155.5"] 
Is there any way to take away the "" marks?

Comment: @FattRyan ..your query basically returns a hash..`.values` give the values of the hash in an array